# How do I get the departmentName alongside the employees first and last names in the combobox?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to add a the departmentName to the corresponding employees.
The code below is my attempt at trying to add the departmentName beside the first and last names but it does not work. Can anyone tell me why.
The picture is what the output should be. But I keep getting an error in my loop. Thanks in advance.

[image: How I want the output to look like]

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        // Ex 6 - Adding the department along side the employees first and last name
        //

        labelStatus.Text = "";

        var selectedemployees = employees.AsQueryable<Employee>();
        var selecteddepartment = departments.AsQueryable<Department>();

        if (selectedemployees.Count() > 0)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();

            foreach (var emp in selectedemployees)
            {
                    selecteddepartment = from dep in departments.AsQueryable<Department>()
                                         where dep.DepartmentId == emp.DepartmentId
                                         select dep;
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(emp.Firstname + ", " + emp.Lastname + ", " + emp.DepartmentName);
            }

            comboBox1.Text = "Employees and Departments Added!";
        }
    }
```

Here is my employee & department entity classes:
DEPARTMENT ENTITY:

```
public class Department
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

EMPLOYEE ENTITY:

```
public class Employee
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phoneno { get; set; }
    public string Entity64 { get; set; }
    public ObjectId DepartmentId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your code appears to function as expected. It displays the department name right beside the employee's name. Your `selectedDepartment` query is never used and will not return results anyway because you're asking it to compare an `int` to a `string`.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: When I hover over the error it says  - "Department" does not contain a definition for 'departmentId' and no extension method 'departmentId' accepting a first argument type "Department"

Comment: this error indicates the the Department class doesn't have a property named `DepartmentId` (or `departmentId`).. does it?.. is the accessor `public` ? ... update your question, include your `Department` Entity class in it for us to review;

Comment: Does `Deparment` contain a definition for `DepartmentId`?

Comment: @Diego No Department does not contain a definition for DepartmentId

Comment: Also in the for loop i need to look up each department name in the department collection where the department id is equal to the employee’s 
DepartmentId field. But what I have written in the foreach loop raises an error

Comment: hmm... well, your "entities" are essentially your `Department` and `Employee` `class` definitions.. **Entity** is similiar to the notion of a `Model`; the subtle (but distinct) difference is context of how it is inititalized (aka you generally retrieve an initialized instance of it from the DbContext); providing us your DbSet/repository insertion methods isn't particular helpful..

Comment: @BrettCaswell my mistake I have made the revision and posted the entities

Comment: @marko, I just realized that you changed the scope of your question/issue.. you can't really do that, because it invalidates the answers and comments... I had to revert the question to an earlier state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minor definition issue you're experiencing requires you to define a property called `DepartmentId` on your `Department` Entity that is accessible.

---

Additionally, I wanted to provide more information to you on `Linq` (not Lamda, however)...

Linq is about expression building, alot of the example and usages are declaring and using anonymous delegates and types, but I think it may serve you better to see explicit examples.

So, include the `Linq.Expressions` assembly/reference in your code namespace.

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
```

also, lets define a Data Transfer Object (DTO).

```
public class EmployeeDepartmentDTO
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

The Following class represent **Would-Be** Entities; Notice that I have declared several Properties relating to `Department` on the `Employee` Entity-Model.

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        this.Departments = new List<Department>();
    }

    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public Department()
    {
        this.Employees = new List<Employee>();
    }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

The following class `ExpressionBuildingExample` depicts a Button Click Event Handler; note that the expressions are initialized, once, outside of the scope of the button click handling function.

I've also added an array of `IQueryable<string>` that is initialized with the queries that utilize each methodology in this example.

A `SelectMany().GroupBy().Select()` method is performed on the collection to **flatten** the IEnumerable instances and combine (or group) the similar elements. (which there will be in this example).

Additionally, I've declared a `static readonly string` for the string formatting.

```
public class ExpressionBuildingExample
{
    private readonly System.Windows.Forms.Label labelStatus = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    private readonly System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();

    // 2 - DepartmentName, 0 - Firstname, 1 - Lastname (reorder for different results)
    private static readonly string itemFormat = "{2} - {0} {1}"; //used in String.Format


    #region "EmployeeDepartmentDTO to string"
    //  If you use a DTO, you'll do a Select<EmployeeDepartmentDTO, String> to produce a string value for each 'element' in the collection;
    private readonly Expression<Func<EmployeeDepartmentDTO, string>> DtoSelectClause = (dto) => String.Format(itemFormat, dto.Firstname, dto.Lastname, dto.DepartmentName);
    #endregion


    #region "Employee Department(s) to string(s)"
    //  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  the following section assumes Department is a Navigation Property of Employee: i.e. `employee.Departments` or `employee.Department`; 
    //  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //  (1 to many Relationship) - return string[]
    private readonly Expression<Func<Employee, string[]>> SelectEmployeeDepartmentsStringClause = (employee) => employee.Departments.Select((department) => String.Format(itemFormat, employee.Firstname, employee.Lastname, department.DepartmentName)).ToArray();
    
    //  (1 to 1 Relationship) - return string
    private readonly Expression<Func<Employee, string>> SelectEmployeeDepartmentStringClause = (employee) => String.Format(itemFormat, employee.Firstname, employee.Lastname, employee.Department.DepartmentName);

    // =====================================================================================================================================
    #endregion
    

    #region "Employee Department(s) to IQueryable<EmployeeDepartmentDTO>"

    // (1 to 1Relationship) - returns EmployeeDepartmentDTO
    private readonly Expression<Func<Employee, EmployeeDepartmentDTO>> SelectEmployeeDepartmentDtoClause = (employee) => new EmployeeDepartmentDTO()
    {
        Firstname = employee.Firstname,
        Lastname = employee.Lastname,
        DepartmentName = employee.Department.DepartmentName
    };

    // (1 to many Relationship) - returns EmployeeDepartmentDTO
    private readonly Expression<Func<Employee, EmployeeDepartmentDTO>> SelectEmployeeDepartmentsDtoClause = (employee) => new EmployeeDepartmentDTO() {
        Firstname = employee.Firstname,
        Lastname =  employee.Lastname,
        DepartmentName = employee.Departments.Where( (department) => department.DepartmentId == employee.DepartmentId ).FirstOrDefault().DepartmentName
    };

    // =====================================================================================================================================
    #endregion


    #region "Employee JOIN Department to IQueryable<EmployeeDepartmentDTO>"
    // This will be used in a Join Statement
    private readonly Expression<Func<Employee, Department, EmployeeDepartmentDTO>> JoinSelectDtoClause = (employee, department) => new EmployeeDepartmentDTO()
    {
        Firstname = employee.Firstname,
        Lastname = employee.Lastname,
        DepartmentName = department.DepartmentName
    };
    // =====================================================================================================================================
    #endregion


    public void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labelStatus.Text = "";

        List<Department> departments = new List<Department>(new Department[] {
            new Department() { DepartmentId = 1, DepartmentName = "Sales" },
            new Department() { DepartmentId = 3, DepartmentName = "Manager" },
            new Department() { DepartmentId = 5, DepartmentName = "Reception" },
            new Department() { DepartmentId = 6, DepartmentName = "Human Resources" },
        });

        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>(new Employee[] {
            new Employee() { 
                Firstname = "Dwight", Lastname = "Schrute", 
                DepartmentId = 1,
                Department = departments.First(d => d.DepartmentId == 1),
                Departments = new List<Department>(departments.Where(d => d.DepartmentId == 1))},
            new Employee() { Firstname = "Jim", Lastname = "Halpert", 
                DepartmentId = 1, 
                Department = departments.First(d => d.DepartmentId == 1),
                Departments = new List<Department>(departments.Where(d => d.DepartmentId == 1))},
            new Employee() { Firstname = "Mimi", Lastname = "Bobeck", DepartmentId = 5,
                Department = departments.First(d => d.DepartmentId == 5),
                Departments = new List<Department>(departments.Where(d => d.DepartmentId == 5))},
            new Employee() { Firstname = "Drew", Lastname = "Carry", DepartmentId = 6,
                Department = departments.First(d => d.DepartmentId == 6),
                Departments = new List<Department>(departments.Where(d => d.DepartmentId == 3))},
            new Employee() { Firstname = "Nigel", Lastname = "Wick", DepartmentId = 3,
                Department = departments.First(d => d.DepartmentId == 3),
                Departments = new List<Department>(departments.Where(d => d.DepartmentId == 3))},
            new Employee() { Firstname = "Micheal", Lastname = "Scott", DepartmentId = 5,
                Department = departments.First(d => d.DepartmentId == 6),
                Departments = new List<Department>(departments.Where(d => d.DepartmentId == 1))}
        });
        
        var queryEmployees = employees.AsQueryable<Employee>();
        var queryDepartments = departments.AsQueryable<Department>();

        

        var querySimple = queryEmployees.Select(SelectEmployeeDepartmentStringClause);
        var queryAdvanced = queryEmployees.Select(SelectEmployeeDepartmentsStringClause).SelectMany(s => s);
        var queryDto = queryEmployees.Select(SelectEmployeeDepartmentDtoClause);
        var queryJoin = queryEmployees.Join(queryDepartments.AsEnumerable(), (emp) => emp.DepartmentId, (dept) => dept.DepartmentId, JoinSelectDtoClause);

        
        var queryAll = new IQueryable<string>[] {
            querySimple,          
            queryAdvanced,
            queryDto.Select(DtoSelectClause),
            queryJoin.Select(DtoSelectClause),
        };

        if (queryAll.Any(q => q.Any())) //queryJoin.Any() + querySimple.Any() + queryDto.Any()
        {
            //  query.AsEnumerable() (or .ToList(), ToArray()) will load/execute/run the query;


            //  SelectMany will Enumerate the collections when it flattens them; thus it will load the queries;
            string[] items = queryAll
                    .SelectMany((q) => q)
                    .GroupBy(str => str).Select(g => g.Key) // the items are all strings (value types), so this will function properly; otherwise every instance would be unique and grouped, unless object.GetHashCode is overridden.
                    .ToArray();

            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(items);
            comboBox1.Text = "Employees and Departments Added!";                
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Results

```
items:= {string[9]}  itemFormat:= "{2} - {0} {1}"

"Sales - Dwight Schrute"
"Sales - Jim Halpert"
"Reception - Mimi Bobeck"
"Human Resources - Drew Carry"
"Manager - Nigel Wick"
"Human Resources - Micheal Scott"
"Manager - Drew Carry"
"Sales - Micheal Scott"
"Reception - Micheal Scott"
```

Comment: I have updated my code and sample picture of my output, thanks to your help I have manged to figure out my dilemma but have run into another problem. Do you have any answers as to why?

Comment: I've refactored the coding sample to a funtional state, representing 4 query relationships and considerations..

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very clear. `Department` does not contain a definition for `DepartmentId`. I think the field you are trying to use is just `Id` in `Deparment class`.

Change your line with this one:

```
selecteddepartment = from dep in departments.AsQueryable<Department>()
    where dep.Id == emp.DepartmentId
    select dep;
```

Comment: I am one step closer.Also in the for loop i need to look up each department name in the department collection where the department id is equal to the employee’s DepartmentId field. But im not sure on how to continue. Any suggestions/examples would be useful

Answer (score 0):

I have found my desired solution.

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        // Ex 6 - Adding the department along side the employees first and last name
        //

        labelStatus.Text = "";

        var selectedemployees = employees.AsQueryable<Employee>();
        var selecteddepartment = departments.AsQueryable<Department>();

        if (selectedemployees.Count() > 0)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();

            foreach (var emp in selectedemployees) 
            {
                    selecteddepartment = from dep in departments.AsQueryable<Department>()
                                         where dep.Id == emp.DepartmentId
                                         select dep;

                    comboBox1.Items.Add(emp.Firstname + ", " + emp.Lastname + ", " + selecteddepartment.FirstOrDefault().DepartmentName);
                }
                comboBox1.Text = "Employee Names and Depts Added!";
            }

        }
```

Comment: I see that you're issue was that the property was `Id` on `Department`, that's why I asked you to post your `Department` class in your question. I figured it was something really minor.. still, there are two issue with your scenerio and code here.. the first is that you should declare a ForeignKey relationship on `Employee.DepartmentId` and `Department.Id` (it will be a 1 to many - or 1 to * - relationship); ---

Comment: ---  your entities should then be updated,. Afterwhich, there should be a list (Collection) of `Employee` on your `Department` entity, and a single `Department` instance/property on your `Employee` enitty. The second issue is the presence of the foreach loop.  You should use my code same below to see how you can build the loop into your expression (query). If you don't create the ForeignKey relationship (and update your entity models),  Then better alternative is to use `Join` or `Include` in your query expression.

Comment: In your current implementation, you will be querying your database/datastore for each `emp in selectedemployees`, plus 1 (your initial query to initialize `selectedemployees`). that is not optimal, and usually avoidable. .